# Oracle SQL to JSON

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm trying to convert a query to JSON format, so I can use it with streaming data. I searched in the oracle documentations how to do it, but I'm getting this error on line 6, what could it be?

> Error: ORA-00406: the COMPATIBLE parameter must be 12.0 or greater
> 00406. 00000 -  "COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be %s or greater"
> *Cause:    The COMPATIBLE initialization parameter is not high
> enough to allow the operation. Allowing the command would make
> the database incompatible with the release specified by the
> current COMPATIBLE parameter.

Oracle documentation: https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/json_object-enhancements-19c

When I run the query that return the database version comes 19.0.0.0

```
SELECT
     JSON_OBJECT(h.loca_nm_local, j.cllo_nm_cluster_log) AS json_data
FROM
     db1.local         h
     LEFT JOIN db1.local_cluster i ON h.loca_sq_local = i.loca_sq_local
     LEFT JOIN db1.cluster_log   j ON i.cllo_sq_cluster_log = j.cllo_sq_cluster_log
WHERE
    ( j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%NEB%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%SOB%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%BC%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%BS%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%BUZ%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%ES-%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%LBR-%'
    OR j.cllo_nm_cluster_log LIKE '%ES0%' )
```

Comment: A side note: Oracle's documentation is located here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, in order to use that function, you must have a minimum COMPATIBLE parameter of "12.0" You can check your current value for the COMPATIBLE parameter with the following query:

```
Select name,value
from v$parameter
where name like 'comp%';
```

You can read the details around the COMPATIBLE parameter here in the oracle documentation, including how to change it (and the ramifications of doing so):

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/what-is-oracle-database-compatibility.html

Comment: I ran the query and returned version 11.2.0.3, I searched and it seems that with this version it is not possible to work with JSON, am I correct?

Even though the database is in version 19.0.0.0 it is not possible to use JSON because of this minimal compatibility?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.